# Are there any reasons to be concerned about the security of "Coin"?

Tags: pci-dss, credit-card

I just came across this:

> https://onlycoin.com/

A credit-card sized device that not only holds the info for as many credit and debit and membership cards as you want (they claim) but also can be swiped just like whichever credit card you select on its interface.

The convenience is obvious, but are there any reasons to question the security?  (For instance, 128-bit bit encryptions sounds pathetic when 2048 bit should be trivially easy to implement and a lot harder to crack. But I'm sure there could be much bigger and more subtle problems that I don't notice.)

Comment: IMHO - credit card "technology" is woefully outdated and should be replaced with something that is more secure.

Comment: I, for one, am more concerned with the usability. What if my phone dies? I can't use my card anymore because it will be out of range. What if the waiter has to walk through several rooms to swipe the card? Bluetooth will be out of range. What if the battery dies on the card? What if there's malware on my smartphone? Most important of all, **what problem does coin solve??** One plastic card instead of three?

Comment: RubberDuck: For some people I think it might be one plastic card instead of 15.  I was in that ball park many years ago, but now I'm down to one credit card, one debit/ATM card, one insurance card, a work ID (which I doubt this can replace) a Driver's License (which I'm sure this can't legally replace), and a AAA membership card.  If I used this I'd add all those infuriatingly annoying "reward" cards that every stupid store makes you use to get their sale prices.

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing the key size of symmetric algorithms such as 128 bit AES and the key size of an asymmetric algorithms like RSA, which would need an estimated 3072 bit key to achieve a similar level of security.

The problems I see are not so much with security. It seems like that would be a slight overall improvement over a regular printed mag stripe card. My concerns are with missing functionality. It won't do EMV. It won't do NFC. It doesn't protect against skimming attacks. And it will be obsolete in 2015.

Comment: You can now lock the Coin to a specific card before handing it over so someone can't skim all your cards.

Comment: It could do more to protect against skimming, such as locking itself after one attempt to read the current mag stripe (perhaps a pressure sensor to tell when it's being squeezed through a reader.)

Comment: The Coin also has anti-skim features now that will trigger an alarm if there are multiple attempts to swipe. I'm not sure if it's configurable, or if you can set the device to stop allowing the card to be read after x attempts, but I know it's there.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how 128 symmetric encryption would be insecure, it's what AES currently offers as well. ( you are mixing symmetric vs asymmetric crypto). According to NIST aes-128 and RSA 2048 are both secure until at least 2030.

Biggest problem is lose one card lose all cards, but if your wallet gets stolen chances are all you cards would be in there as well.

One benefit is that it does not advertise the card numbers and cvv number, so it would be pretty useless.

As mentioned in previous questions about Coin the biggest issue will be that not all countries support swipe, so take it outside of the US and you will have a problem.

Obviously no one has had a go at it so far to attack the card technically, so there might be issues which don't exist in theory, but which do exist in reality.

Answer (score 1):

One of my biggest initial concerns was handing it over to a waiter who would then be able to skim all of your cards. This, however, has been addressed and the user now has the ability to lock the Coin to a specific card.

The Coin also comes with features like a proximity alert (if you walk off and leave it) and a multiple swipe warning (someone is trying to skim all your cards). Most wallets don't have these features so there are additional benefits to security.

It would seem it has a limited lifespan going forwards, but on the security front it doesn't seem too dissimilar to carrying around all your cards in your wallet anyway.